# What kind of purple stone is this?

Tags: geology, geophysics, rocks, geochemistry, mineralogy

I found this stone and I do not know what type of stone is this?
[image]

Answer (score 7):

That's amethyst, a violet version of quartz

[See here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amethyst)

Comment: It's also relatively common, so unless it's really big, it's not worth much.